# How to load .geojson file w/ properties and polygons into SQL table?

Tags: geojson, sql, azure

I have an Azure SQL table:

```
-- Create the table in the specified schema
CREATE TABLE dbo.geoTest_DEV
(
    fAssetId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    fAssetGeoId [NVARCHAR] (50),
    fAssetType [NVARCHAR](255),
    fAssetStatus [NVARCHAR](255),
    fAssetDesc [NVARCHAR](255),
    fGeoType [NVARCHAR](50),
    fGeoCoord [GEOGRAPHY]
);
GO
```

I have set up an Azure Blob Storage container as an external data source for this database. This holds .geojson files to be loaded into the Azure SQL table:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL uploadGeo
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = '<bigLongString>';
```

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE geoStorage
    WITH (
        TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
        LOCATION = 'https://mycoolthing.blob.core.windows.net',
        CREDENTIAL = uploadGeo
    );
```

Here is the schema of `geotest.geojson`:
**NOTE:** There are multiple polygons in the actual file. This is just a sample of a single feature.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "geometryId": "1",
        "assetType": "residential building",
        "assetStatus": "active",
        "assetDesc": "Bills place"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -121.39254742860793,
              47.668080416965564
            ],
            [
              -121.39254742860793,
              47.66804784193947
            ],
            [
              -121.39257156848907,
              47.66804603221521
            ],
            [
              -121.39257156848907,
              47.668002598814054
            ],
            [
              -121.39236772060394,
              47.668002598814054
            ],
            [
              -121.39236772060394,
              47.668080416965564
            ],
            [
              -121.39254742860793,
              47.668080416965564
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I can't quite figure out how to get each of the `properties`, the `geometry type` AND the `geometry coordinates` objects into the SQL table in a single call.

Here is where I'm stuck:

```
DECLARE @geoJson NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @geoJson = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK 'geoTest.geojson',
    DATA_SOURCE = 'geoUploads',
    SINGLE_CLOB) as JSON

INSERT INTO dbo.geoSQL_DEV (fGeoCoord)
SELECT
  geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON ((' + STRING_AGG(CAST(Long + ' ' + Lat as varchar(max)), ',') + '))',4326).ReorientObject() AS fGeoCoord
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        Long,
        Lat
    FROM
        OPENJSON(@geoJson, '$.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0]')
        WITH
            (
                Long varchar(100) '$[0]',
                Lat varchar(100) '$[1]'
            )
)d

GO

DECLARE @geoJson1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @geoJson1 = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK 'geoTest.geojson',
    DATA_SOURCE = 'geoUploads',
    SINGLE_CLOB) as JSON

INSERT INTO dbo.geoSQL_DEV (fAssetGeoId, fAssetType, fAssetStatus, fAssetDesc, fGeoType)
SELECT
  fAssetGeoId,
    fAssetType,
    fAssetStatus,
    fAssetDesc, 
    fGeoType
FROM
OPENJSON(@geoJson1, '$.features')
    WITH (
        fAssetGeoId [NVARCHAR] (50) '$.properties.geometryId',
        fAssetType [NVARCHAR](300) '$.properties.assetType',
        fAssetStatus [NVARCHAR](300) '$.properties.assetStatus',
        fAssetDesc [NVARCHAR](300) '$.properties.assetDesc',
        fGeoType [NVARCHAR](300) '$.geometry.type'
    )

GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.geoSQL_DEV
```

ALMOST THERE! This results in:

[image]

I just need to figure out how to insert each `fGeoCoord` in the correct record instead of in the single record as shown.

ANY IDEAS?

Comment: use the azure maps api? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/data/uploadpreview - example POST https://atlas.microsoft.com/mapData/upload?subscription-key=[subscription-key]&api-version=1.0&dataFormat=geojson

Comment: I'm using the Azure Maps API for some things. In this case, I'd like to understand how to insert geojson from Azure Blob Storage directly into SQL.

Comment: Could really use some expertise here. Need help writing BOTH `geography::STPolyFromText` and `properties` to the same record. What does that SQL syntax look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 years too late for you @Seadude and you surely solved this but here is my answer that may save someone else some time:

```
--CREATE TABLE dbo.geoTest_DEV
--(
--    fAssetId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
--    fAssetGeoId [NVARCHAR] (50),
--    fAssetType [NVARCHAR](255),
--    fAssetStatus [NVARCHAR](255),
--    fAssetDesc [NVARCHAR](255),
--    fGeoType [NVARCHAR](50),
--    fGeoCoord [GEOGRAPHY]
--);

DECLARE @geoJson NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @geoJson = '{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "geometryId": "1",
        "assetType": "residential building",
        "assetStatus": "active",
        "assetDesc": "Bills place"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -121.39254742860793,
              47.668080416965564
            ],
            [
              -121.39254742860793,
              47.66804784193947
            ],
            [
              -121.39257156848907,
              47.66804603221521
            ],
            [
              -121.39257156848907,
              47.668002598814054
            ],
            [
              -121.39236772060394,
              47.668002598814054
            ],
            [
              -121.39236772060394,
              47.668080416965564
            ],
            [
              -121.39254742860793,
              47.668080416965564
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}'

INSERT INTO [dbo].[geoTest_DEV] (fAssetGeoId, fAssetType, fAssetStatus, fAssetDesc, fGeoType, fGeoCoord )


SELECT geometryId as fAssetGeoId, assetType as fAssetType, assetStatus as fAssetStatus,  assetDesc as fAssetDesc, [type] as fGeoType, geography::STGeomFromText(CONCAT('POLYGON((',STUFF(coords,1,2,''),'))'),4326).MakeValid().ReorientObject() AS fGeoCoord
FROM (
    SELECT   properties.*, j1.*, j2.coords
    FROM 
        OPENJSON(@geoJson, '$.features') j
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.[value], '$.properties') WITH (
        geometryId NVARCHAR (50) '$.geometryId',
        assetType NVARCHAR(300) '$.assetType',
        assetStatus NVARCHAR(300) '$.assetStatus',
        assetDesc NVARCHAR(300) '$.assetDesc')properties
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.[value], '$.geometry') WITH (
        [type] NVARCHAR(300) '$.type') j1  
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT  concat(', ',x , ' ' , y) 
        FROM OPENJSON(j.[value],'$.geometry.coordinates[0]')WITH (
        x float '$[0]', y float '$[1]' )FOR XML PATH('')) j2 (coords)
) p
GO
```

[image: Result]

This will work if there are only polygons in your dataset.
To do the same with a geojson containing mixed geometry types, the solution is to flesh out the query with more CROSS APPLY statements as demonstrated in the top answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371128/issue-on-trying-to-query-geojson-multipolygons-in-sql-server-2016)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I was unable to complete the POC due to this (and some other) issues. Now maybe I can revisit!